# Why can I not implement a method here?

Tags: javascript, methods

Here is the code:

```
function startAnimation() {
      setInterval( doAnimationStep, 40) // 40 ms = 25 frames per second
      this.stopAnimation= stopAnimation(){
        document.getElementById("buttonStop")= setInterval(doAnimationStep, 0)

      }
}
```

My IDE does underscore the curly braces:

[image]

I started programming last week and I'm really struggling with methods now...

Comment: method declarations like `name () { code }` are only allowed within objects and classes. Not within expressions.

Comment: Did you mean to do: `this.stopAnimation = function stopAnimation() {`?

Comment: When you hover over the underscored characters, what is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have methods in [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) and [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions). However you can create functions within functions. Therefore you could change your code to the following and have similar behavior.

```js
function startAnimation() {
  const setInterval = (doAnimationStep, 40) // 40 ms = 25 frames per second
  const stopAnimation = () => {
    document.getElementById("buttonStop")= setInterval(doAnimationStep, 0)
  }
}
```

On another note: I am not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this line:

```js
document.getElementById("buttonStop")= setInterval(doAnimationStep, 0)
```

[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) returns a non-zero number and [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) and you're assigning one to the other.